# Air quality meter name

Tags: translation, meaning, mandarin, vocabulary

[image]I have an air quality detector meter.

It has the name of the manufactures written on the bottom.

What's the english translation?

Does this manufacturer have a web page?

Thanks

EDIT:

In the web page https://www.chinahao.com/product/538115265141/, clicking the "DETAILS" tab, there's this pic a the end. Is this the manufacturer?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

阿格瑞斯 is seemingly a transliteration of "Aceras"

'[Aceras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aceras)' is a genus of orchid

This 阿格瑞斯 company in Shenzhen specialized in air quality detection and solution since 2003

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you identify the manufacturer of the 阿格瑞斯 air meter in any of the online shopping pages? The model is a WP6912. https://item.jd.com/10175823103.html

Comment: @Ron Bergen The manufacturer 阿格瑞斯 itself  seems to be obscured, but it is a very prominent brand on these shopping pages, you can contact the shopping pages to learn more

Comment: Please check my edit. Does it say on the pic if it is the manufacturer?Thanks.

Comment: See my edition at the bottom